# How to not display key in textbox

Tags: c#

I'd like to know how to solve my little problem. 
Im making calc with C# and have problem there:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            IfNumbersExist();
            SelectedOperation = Operation.Add;
            IsSecondNumberBeingEntered = true;
        }
```

So the problem is that when I'm pressing Add key textBox data is clearing, but '+' is still there. 
How to clear whole textBox to not display '+' too ?

Thanks

Comment: The '+' is not still there. If is added to the TextBox **after** the event has been handled. Use Tim S's solution to stop handling the `Add` key and thus entering a '+'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something of a shot in the dark, but try adding this somewhere inside your `if` statement:

```
e.Handled = true;
```